# Saving an element linked to next element with NHibernate; invalid index n for this sqlparamatercollection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an object, PlaylistItem, which saved fine when referencing its next PlaylistItem by ID. I am encountering an exception when trying to modify this code to reference the actual PlaylistItem object itself. I understand that the issue is caused by a duplicate mapping in my hbm.xml file. However, I have not been able to find a solution for my scenario.

Here is PlaylistItem.hbm.xml currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Streamus" namespace="Streamus.Backend.Domain">

  <class name="PlaylistItem" table="[PlaylistItems]" lazy="false" >
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="Id" />
      <key-many-to-one name="Playlist" column="PlaylistId"/>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="Title" not-null="true" />

    <many-to-one name="Video" column="VideoId" not-null="true" />

    <many-to-one name="NextItem" not-null="true">
      <column name="NextItemId" />
      <column name="PlaylistId" />
    </many-to-one>
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am able to avoid this exception by modifying the NextItem many-to-one relationship such that it has the properties 'insert="false" update="false".' However, doing so causes NextItem to always be NULL in the database.

Here is the related class:

```
public class PlaylistItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Playlist Playlist { get; set; }
    public PlaylistItem NextItem { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Video Video { get; set; }

    public PlaylistItem()
    {
        //  Id shall be generated by the client. This is OK because it is composite key with 
        //  PlaylistId which is generated by the server. 
        Id = Guid.Empty;
        Title = string.Empty;
    }

    private int? _oldHashCode;
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Once we have a hash code we'll never change it
        if (_oldHashCode.HasValue)
            return _oldHashCode.Value;

        bool thisIsTransient = Equals(Id, Guid.Empty);

        // When this instance is transient, we use the base GetHashCode()
        // and remember it, so an instance can NEVER change its hash code.
        if (thisIsTransient)
        {
            _oldHashCode = base.GetHashCode();
            return _oldHashCode.Value;
        }
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        PlaylistItem other = obj as PlaylistItem;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        // handle the case of comparing two NEW objects
        bool otherIsTransient = Equals(other.Id, Guid.Empty);
        bool thisIsTransient = Equals(Id, Guid.Empty);
        if (otherIsTransient && thisIsTransient)
            return ReferenceEquals(other, this);

        return other.Id.Equals(Id);
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown regardless of whether NextItem has been defined or is null. I am firm on my need to use a composite key to uniquely represent a PlaylistItem.

What are my options? I am unsure of how to troubleshoot this further.

Here is a screenshot of my object's watch just before saving:

[image]

As stated, I have also attempted to save with NextItem being null. In addition, I have tried having NextItem be another PlaylistItem entirely (so that PlaylistItem is not self-referential.) Neither of these changes had any effect.

Here is a screenshot of the exception:

[image]

The exception reads, "Invalid index 5 for this SqlParamaterCollection with Count=5." There is no inner exception defined.

Here are PlaylistItem's constructors, referenced in the screenshot:

```
public PlaylistItem()
{
    //  Id shall be generated by the client. This is OK because it is composite key with 
    //  PlaylistId which is generated by the server. 
    Id = Guid.Empty;
    Title = string.Empty;
}

public PlaylistItem(Guid id, string title, Video video)
    : this()
{
    Id = id;
    Title = title;
    Video = video;
}
```

Here is Playlist's constructor as well as its AddItem method:

```
public Playlist()
{
    Id = Guid.Empty;
    Title = string.Empty;
    Items = new List<PlaylistItem>();
}

public Playlist(string title)
    : this()
{
    Title = title;
}

/// <summary>
///     Add a PlaylistItem to the Playlist's PlaylistItem collection by inserting
///     the PlaylistItem at the end of the linked list. Adjust the links
///     to accomodate the PlaylistItem and set the Playlist's FirstItem
///     if necessary.
/// </summary>
public void AddItem(PlaylistItem playlistItem)
{
    if (Items.Count == 0)
    {
        playlistItem.NextItem = playlistItem;
        playlistItem.PreviousItem = playlistItem;
        FirstItem = playlistItem;
    }
    else
    {
        //  Adjust our linked list and add the item.
        FirstItem.PreviousItem.NextItem = playlistItem;
        playlistItem.PreviousItem = FirstItem.PreviousItem;

        FirstItem.PreviousItem = playlistItem;
        playlistItem.NextItem = FirstItem;
    }

    Items.Add(playlistItem);
    playlistItem.Playlist = this;
}
```

Here is PlaylistManager's constructor and its Save method:

```
public PlaylistManager(IPlaylistDao playlistDao, IPlaylistItemDao playlistItemDao, IVideoDao videoDao)
{
    PlaylistDao = playlistDao;
    PlaylistItemDao = playlistItemDao;
    VideoDao = videoDao;
}

public void Save(Playlist playlist)
{
    try
    {
        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.BeginTransaction();

        playlist.ValidateAndThrow();
        PlaylistDao.Save(playlist);

        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.CommitTransaction();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Error(exception);
        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.RollbackTransaction();
        throw;
    }
}
```

The PlaylistDao's Save method is simply a wrapper around NHibernateSession.Save(entity);

Comment: Can you add the exception to the question?

Comment: Sure, but it is a heavily documented exception. One moment.

Comment: Can you add code for the constructor that you use in your screenshot, Initialization of PlaylistManager, Initialization of Playlist?

Comment: I have added the logic you asked to see to the original post. However, I believe the issue can be fully understood just through PlaylistItem.hbm.xml. NextItem's many-to-one relationship references the PlaylistId column. This column has already been dehydrated due to the key-many-to-one entry referencing PlaylistId. You cannot disable insert/update for a key. If I disable insert/update on my many-to-one, NextItemId is never inserted into the database. There is no way to indicate that I do not wish to insert/update one of the columns of my many-to-one entry.